# select 2 creates a large space after opening dropdown menu

Tags: css, select, bootstrap-4

I'm using a select as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('.select2-multiple-choices').select2(
   {          
     placeholder: 'Select one or more fields'     
   });    
});    

.select2-selection--multiple:after
{
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 right:10px;
 top:15px;
 width:0;
 height:0;
 border-left: 5px solid transparent;
 border-right: 5px solid transparent;
 border-top: 5px solid #888;
}   

.outer {
padding-top: 40px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
padding-left: 30%;
padding-right: 30%;
background-color: #eee;
}


.select2-container
{
width: 100% !important;
}

 <div class="outer">
 <select class="select2-multiple-choices select2-choice"  multiple="multiple" 
 th:field="*{parameters}">
 <option th:each="option : ${searchoptions}" th:value="${option.getKey()}" 
   th:text="${option.getValue()}"></option>
  </select>
  </div>
```

But When the dropdown menu is opened, a right-space larger than the actual page is created as you can see here [image: Before]
Before dropdown is opened

[image]

After the dropdown menu is opened

How can I avoid such behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce the error you're describing (see the [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/yfnL1vq0/12/)).

---

**UPDATE**

The problem is caused by the `width: 100% !important;` set to the `select2-container` when you click on the dropdown.

**Solution 1**

Add the following CSS:

```
html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**Solution 2**

Add the following CSS:

```
.select2-container {
  max-width: 335px;
}
```

Comment: You really helped me to find the problem, namely the container around the select. I updated the question. Do you know why that box is generating the glitch?

Comment: Thanks, I guess that this command hides eventual overflows of the sub-containers.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "overflow-x: clip;" and "position: relative;" to the parent of select2-container.

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: clip !important;
    position: relative;
}
```

As the select2-container has position absolute, the width will work properly only when the parent has position relative.

Hope it works for you.
Cheers